# Будет ли оптимальным применять mean(-1) для выхода TransformerEncoder?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Классы типа Transformer имеют на выходе ту же размерность, что и на входе. Если мне нужно лишь одно значение, будет ли оптимальным применить функцию mean для сжатия всех выходящих значений? Т.е. нужно преобразовать некотрую последовательность не фиксированной длины в фиксированное количество выходов, какие варианты для этого оптимальны?

Например такие варианты:

```
# трасформер возвращает тензор: [batch,sequence,d_model]
# и все выходные значения по каждому батчу ужимаются в одно значение
result = self.transformer(x).flatten(1,2).mean(1)
```

или вариант, если на выходе нужно несколько значений:

```
# размерность d_model преобразуется к желаемой размерности
# при помощи nn.Linear(d_model, needSize),
# а вся последовательность ужимается
# на выходе: [batch,needSize]
x = self.transformer(x)
result = self.linear(x).mean(1)
```

или вариант наоборот:

```
# сначала последовательность пакуется при помощи mean,
# а потом при помощи nn.Linear(d_model, needSize)
# преобразуется к желаемой размерности
result = self.linear(self.transformer(x).mean(1))
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы узнать критерии оптимальности. Считаю, что вопрос нужно уточнить.

Comment: Вероятно критерий оптимальности это более быстрое и качественное научивание сетки желаемому выходу. Если есть другие варианты, на которые нужно ориентироваться при обучении сеток, то мне это так же было бы интересно узнать.

Comment: Если следовать мануалам из питорча, то там нужно на выход сетки дублировать входные значения со сдвигом на одну позицию. Но это при генерации текста. Но ведь эти трансформеры используются не только для генерации текста.